# dataUrl in jqGrid calls every time

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid with inline editing. In one column there is dropdown list and pulls data from web service.

```js
$("#Freight").jqGrid({
  datatype: 'xmlstring',
  datastr: xmlString,
  mtype: 'GET',
  ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
  xmlReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "DocumentsAdditionalExpenses", row: 'row' },
  colNames: ['ExpenseCode', 'Feight Name', 'Remarks', 'Tax Code', 'Total Tax Amount', 'Distribution Method', 'Amount'],
  colModel: [
                    { name: 'ExpenseCode', index: 'ExpenseCode', hidden: true, key: true },
                    { name: 'FreightName', index: 'FreightName', width: 100 },
                    { name: 'Remarks', index: 'Remarks', editable: true, edittype: 'text', width: 150 },
                    { name: 'TaxCode', index: 'TaxCode', editable: true,
                     width: 100,
                     edittype: 'select',
                     formatter: 'select',
                     editoptions: { aysnc: false, dataUrl: clientURL,
                      buildSelect: function (data) {
                       var v = data.replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
                       response = $.parseXML(v);
                       $response = $(response);
                       var s = '<select>';
                       $response.find('FreightExpense row').each(function (index) {
                        var code = $(this).find('Code').text();
                        var name = $(this).find('Name').text();
                        s += '<option value="' + code + '">' + name + '</option>';
                       });
                       return s + "</select>";
                      }
                     },
                     formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *', label: 'Name' }
                    },
                    { name: 'TaxSum', index: 'TaxSum', width: 120 },
                    { name: 'DistributionMethod', index: 'DistributionMethod', editable: true,
                     width: 150,
                     edittype: "select",
                     formatter: 'select',
                     editoptions: {
                      value: "aedm_Equally:Equally;aedm_None:None;aedm_Quantity:Quantity;aedm_RowTotal:RowTotal;aedm_Volume:Volume;aedm_Weight:Weight"
                     }
                    },
                    { name: 'LineTotal', index: 'LineTotal', editable: true, edittype: 'text' }
               ],
  viewrecords: true,
  gridview: true,
  onSelectRow: function (id) {
   if (id && id !== lastSelection) {
    var grid = $("#Freight");
    grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSelection);
    grid.jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
    lastSelection = id;
   }
  },
  height: 150,
  width: 650,
  viewrecords: true,
  gridview: true,
  rownumbers: true,
  loadonce: true,
  scrollOffset: 0
 });
```

I have observed two things which I don't understand.

1. Why the width of dropdown is greater than the column width. I want to fix its width based on the column. If size of the column get increased, width of dropdown should also increase.

Please see below screen shot
[image]

[image]
2. Whenever I click on grid row to edit it calls web service, I don't understand this, why it is calling everytime when the data is fixed for every row for that perticular column.

Can any body guide me on this two topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> your first question

**Why the width of dropdown is greater than the column width. I want to fix its width based on the column. If size of the column get increased, width of dropdown should also increase.**

The width of dropdown is greater because of the option lists .The text part of the options is too wide to come under the column **TaxCode**.You can do either thing :-

1)-Increase the **TaxCode** column width .

```
  { name: 'TaxCode', index: 'TaxCode', editable: true,
                    width: 100,   //change this as per requirement
```

2)- Get a horizontal scroll inside the option list (which i don't think is a good idea as jqGrid provides you the way to increase column width.)

You change your **TaxCode** column width depending upon your dropdown width.Then it will solve your this issue "If size of the column get increased, width of dropdown should also increase."

> your second question

**Whenever I click on grid row to edit it calls web service, I don't understand this, why it is calling everytime when the data is fixed for every row for that perticular column.**

This is happening because you must have called your **WebService** on jqGrid row click event . Check once and if it is so , then move that piece of code(I guess you are doing this by **Ajax**) to directly under `document-ready`(if you want this grid on load) .

> One more

**Width of the dropdown list is higher than the column**

Decrease the width of **Quantity** column as you will be doing for **TaxCode** column.

Hope it help !

Comment: clear about the first doubt. but what about 2nd, actually I found this snippet on internet, so I used it. I want call this ajax only once and set the values of dropdownlist instead of calling web service every click on row. My problem is If I get the data from ajax out the jqgrid block then I don't know how to set the option / values for select

Comment: you can do this simply by calling jqGrid in `document-ready` binding all the data you want from web server .you can bind your dropdown lists as well with the data coming from web service

Comment: how to bind this in jqGrid Column. If you closely look in the column "Distribution Method", it has fixed values, How do I set such values at runtime.

Comment: One more thing regarding 1st query, if you closely look into "Distribution Method" text value is very small, but still it is greater then column size. Please look the width of text value  (dropdownlist - figure 2)

Comment: Write an ajax call for getting all the values to bind at runtime.Then in ajax success , write your code for jqgrid and wherever you have to bind data in jqgrid columns whether it's a simple text or dropdown texts just use data parameter of success function.The data parameter will be holding all the required runtime values to be binded inside columns.Hope I am clear this time